# Spring Boot Configuration skip registration on multiple @Profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I've a Spring Boot application with different Profile setup : `dev`, `prod`, `qc`, `console` etc.

The two configuration classes are setup as follows. `MyConfigurationA` should be registered for all profiles except `console`. `MyConfigurationB` should be registered except for `console` and `dev`.

When I run the application with profile `console`, the `MyConfigurationA` doesn't get registered - which is fine. But `MyConfigurationB` gets registered - which I do not want. I've setup the `@Profile` annotation as follows to not register the `MyConfigurationB` for profile  `console` and `dev` .

But the `MyConfigurationB` is getting registered when I run the application with profile `console`.

```
@Profile({ "!" + Constants.PROFILE_CONSOLE ,  "!" + Constants.PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT })
```

---

The documentation ( http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)  has an example of including one profile and excluding the other. In my example I'm excluding both as `@Profile({"!p1", "!p2"}):`

> @Profile({"p1", "!p2"}), registration will occur if
>   profile 'p1' is active **OR** if profile 'p2' is not active.

**My question is :** How can we skip registration of the configurations of both profiles? `@Profile({"!p1", "!p2"})` is doing OR operation. We need AND operation here.

---

The code :

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ "!" + Constants.PROFILE_CONSOLE  })
public class MyConfigurationA {
    static{
        System.out.println("MyConfigurationA registering...");
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile({ "!" + Constants.PROFILE_CONSOLE ,  "!" + Constants.PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT }) // doesn't exclude both, its OR condition
public class MyConfigurationB {
    static{
        System.out.println("MyConfigurationB registering...");
    }
}

public final class Constants {
    public static final String PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT = "dev";
    public static final String PROFILE_CONSOLE = "console";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`@Profile({"!console", "!dev"})` means (NOT console) **OR** (NOT dev) which is true if you run your app with the profile 'console'.
To solve this you can create a custom [Condition](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html):

```
public class NotConsoleAndDevCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Environment environment = context.getEnvironment();
        return !environment.acceptsProfiles("console", "dev");
    }
}
```

And apply the condition via the [@Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) annotation to the Configuration:

```
@Conditional(NotConsoleAndDevCondition.class)
public class MyConfigurationB {
```

Comment: Instead of creating a custom condition, you can use profile expression(logical expression with profile as operands) with the @Profile annotation. ex: @Profile({"!p1 & !p2"})

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html

Comment: As of latest spring updates @RanjanMohanty's answer is concise, logical and works as intended

Answer (score 26):

Starting with Spring 5.1 you can use [expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Profiles.html#of-java.lang.String...-) in `@Profile` annotation. Read more in the [@Profile documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html). Example:

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ "!console & !dev" }) 
public class MyConfigurationB {
    static{
        System.out.println("MyConfigurationB registering...");
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is documented but does not seem to work as advertised

Comment: This approach works only starting with [Spring 5.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Profiles.html#of-java.lang.String...-) => Spring Boot 2.1 or later

Answer (score 5):

With newer versions of Spring, the `acceptsProfiles` method which accepts strings has been deprecated.

To do the equivalent work as in [Cyril's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35252894/1079354), you would need to leverage the [new method parameter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Profiles.html#of-java.lang.String...-).  This newer format also gives you the flexibility to author profile expressions which are more powerful than what was in place prior, thus eliminating the need to negate the entire `acceptsProfiles` expression itself.

```
public class NotConsoleAndDevCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        Environment environment = context.getEnvironment();
        return environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("!console & !dev"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be instead of excluding the 2 profiles (console, dev) you can just include all the others

```
@Profile({"qc", "prod"})
```